# Tensorflow 2.0 Keras Custom Metric manual tf.print not matching returned metric value while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a deep-learning model that will output various labelled diseases. The inputs are both text (doctor's notes) and scalar clinical data. The outputs are labels. Any one patient may have multiple diseases. Hence, this is a multi-label problem.

The output is also extremely sparse. A naive accuracy test (simply generating a zeros matrix of equal shape to the true labels) resulted in around 92% accuracy. Therefore, one of the metrics I am using to evaluate performance is Hamming Loss (number of incorrect labels divided by total number of labels). In order to test whether or not I wrote the correct function, I am using tf.print during the training process to see if what I calculate by hand matches what is being calculated in code.

Here is the hamming_loss function (based on this function here: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.7.1/tensorflow_addons/metrics/hamming.py#L56-L130).

```
def hamming_loss(y, y_hat, thresh=0.8, use_thresh=True, mode='multilabel'):
    if use_thresh is False:
        threshold = tf.reduce_max(y_hat, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        # make sure [0, 0, 0] doesn't become [1, 1, 1]
        # Use abs(x) > eps, instead of x != 0 to check for zero
        y_pred = tf.logical_and(y_hat >= threshold, tf.abs(y_hat) > 1e-12)
    else:
        y_pred = y_hat > thresh

    y_true = tf.cast(y, tf.int32)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.int32)
    shape = tf.cast(tf.shape(y)[-1], tf.int32)

    #tf.print(y, summarize = -1)
    #tf.print('\n')
    #tf.print(y_pred, summarize = -1)
    #tf.print(shape)
    #tf.print(y_hat, summarize = -1)
    if mode == 'multiclass':
        nonzero = tf.cast(
            tf.math.count_nonzero(y_true * y_pred, axis=-1), tf.float32)
        return 1.0 - nonzero

    else:
        nonzero = tf.cast(
            tf.math.count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=-1), tf.int32)
        #tf.print(nonzero, summarize=-1)
        tf.print(nonzero/shape, summarize=-1)
        return nonzero/shape
```

Here is my network (and yes, it is probably needlessly deep/large, but I am in the prototyping phase and just trying out various structures):

```
nlp_input = Input(shape=(1024,), name='nlp_input')
lr = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)
meta_input = Input(shape=(24,), name='meta_input')
hidden_m1 = Dense(2000, activation=lr,kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=0.0001)
                  )(meta_input)
hidden_m2 = Dense(200, activation=lr,
                  )(hidden_m1)
hidden_m3 = Dense(100, activation=lr,
                  )(hidden_m2)
hidden_m4 = Dense(10, activation='relu',
                  )(hidden_m3)



hidden1 = Dense(5000, activation=lr,kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=0.0001)
                )(nlp_input)
hidden2 = Dense(3000, activation=lr
                )(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(3000, activation=lr,
                )(hidden2)
hidden4 = Dense(768, activation=lr,
                 )(hidden3)
hidden5 = Dense(500, activation=lr,
                )(hidden4)
hidden6 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(hidden5)
conc = concatenate([hidden6, hidden_m4])
conch1 = Dense(1000, activation =lr, kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=0.0001))(conc)
conch2 = Dense(500, activation =lr)(conch1)
conch3 = Dense(500, activation =lr)(conch2)
conch4 = Dense(100, activation ='relu')(conch3)
acti = Dense(15, 'sigmoid')(conch4)
model = Model(inputs=[nlp_input, meta_input], outputs=[acti])
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
model.compile(loss=focal_loss(), optimizer=opt,metrics=[tf_prec,tf_rec, hamming_loss])
print(model.summary())
```

For simplicity, just to debug my hamming_loss function, I run with a batch-size equal to 1 and print out the hamming_loss each step. Here are a few steps:

```
Train on 1315 samples, validate on 328 samples
0.066666666666666666
   1/1315 [..............................] - ETA: 12:54 - loss: 6.6111 - tf_prec: 0.2000 - tf_rec: 1.0000 - hamming_loss: 0.06670.066666666666666666
   2/1315 [..............................] - ETA: 8:16 - loss: 6.5891 - tf_prec: 0.2000 - tf_rec: 1.0000 - hamming_loss: 0.0667 0.13333333333333333
0.13333333333333333
   4/1315 [..............................] - ETA: 4:27 - loss: 6.5504 - tf_prec: 0.2500 - tf_rec: 1.0000 - hamming_loss: 0.10000.26666666666666666
0.2
   6/1315 [..............................] - ETA: 3:10 - loss: 6.5065 - tf_prec: 0.3000 - tf_rec: 1.0000 - hamming_loss: 0.14440.066666666666666666
0.2
   8/1315 [..............................] - ETA: 2:31 - loss: 6.4611 - tf_prec: 0.3187 - tf_rec: 1.0000 - hamming_loss: 0.14170.2
0.066666666666666666
  10/1315 [..............................] - ETA: 2:08 - loss: 6.4265 - tf_prec: 0.2800 - tf_rec: 0.9000 - hamming_loss: 0.14000.066666666666666666
0.066666666666666666
  12/1315 [..............................] - ETA: 1:52 - loss: 6.3848 - tf_prec: 0.2542 - tf_rec: 0.8333 - hamming_loss: 0.12780.066666666666666666
0.066666666666666666
```

I am completely mystified as to why the hamming_loss returned by the function does not match up with the hamming loss being manually printed out each step? I am still fairly new to TensorFlow-Keras, so is there something simply going on behind the scenes that I just not aware of?

Comment: Oh, it should be noted that the printed out hamming_loss matches what I calculate by hand, but the hamming_loss being returned by the training is incorrect per my by-hand calculation

Comment: I believe I solved the problem. I was failing to properly wrap the function inside of class as per the documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate. After following the example there under "Custom Metrics" I was able to receive expected output.